# How to filter FrequentItemset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a beginner question about filtering `FrequetItemset` with Scala .

The code starts by the book :

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

 val transactions: RDD[Array[String]] = data.map(s => s.trim.split(','))

 val fpg = new FPGrowth()
 .setMinSupport(0.04)
 .setNumPartitions(10)

  val model = fpg.run(transactions)
```

Now I'd like to filter out items start with `'aaa'` , for example `"aaa_ccc"`, from result

I tried :

```
val filtered_result = model.freqItemsets.itemset.filter{ item => startwith("aaa")}
```

and

```
val filtered_result = model.freqItemsets.filter( itemset.items => startwith("aaa"))
```

and

```
val filtered_result = model.freqItemsets.filter( itemset => items.startwith("aaa"))
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the suggested codes would not compile. So I am not sure if the problem you are talking about is why is it not compiling or is it that you get wrong results.

Scala collections can be filtered using filter method and passing method as a parameter, which can be written in a couple of ways:

```
coll filter { item => filterLogic(item) }
```

so to filter freqItemsets you would use something like:

```
model.freqItemsets filter { itemSet => filterLogic(itemSet) }
```

If you wanted to filter all freqItemsets that contain at least one string that starts with "aaa"

```
model.freqItemsets filter { itemSet => itemSet.items exists { item => item.startsWith("aaa") }
```

Or if your goal was to filter items inside the freqItemset then:

```
model.freqItemsets map { itemSet => itemSet.copy(items = itemSet filter { _.startsWith("aaa") }) }
```

Note that in Scala you can use:
`someCollection filter { item => item.startsWith("string") }` which is the same as: `someCollection filter { _.startsWith("string") }`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice explanations . Thanks ! I'm new to scala , sometime code contains period , sometime space between methods . Why ?

Comment: Lets say you have an instance of class that contains method foo.
It would look like this:
`class A {
def foo(bar: A) = ???
}`

Then you can use method as:
`val a = new A
val b = new A
a foo b
a.foo(b)`

Edit: In Scala everything is a function, even the + operator you are using for summing two Ints such as 1 + 2. You could write it as: `1.+(2)`

Answer (score 1):

`items` is an `Array[String]`. If you want to `filter` any itemset which contains item which is starts with `aaa` you'll need something like this:

```
model.freqItemsets.filter(_.items.exists(_.startsWith("aaa")))
```